# can we read only email name and surname from 100 resumes at a time and later automate them in excel sheet in specific rows and columns using python

Tags: python, excel, automation

however this is my code to extract email , its getting executed without errors but not able to get output, iam a beginner in python

```
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
import re

def get_cv_email(self,cv_path):
    cv_path ='C:\\Users\\bgbeldhe\\Desktop\\trial\\Achour_Raed.pdf'
    pagenums = set()
    output = StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)
    infile = open(cv_path, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
    email = match.group(0)
    return email
```

Comment: do you have any main code? All you've done is define a function that you haven't called

Comment: Use a debugger or add "print" calls to find out what the relevant variables contain during execution.

Comment: All i have is that code only,i called the function after seeing your comment but its still the same result @AndrewAllen